# Strategy to help classifiers cope with ambiguous examples

Tags: time-series, random-forest, multi-class

I have a machine learning problem where sometimes the training data will *correctly* have two or more similar/same training examples with different class labels. As an over-simplified example, let us say we are trying to identify radio stations based on the songs that they play. The training data may look like:

Turn around - Radio 1
All out of love - Radio 1
Changes - Radio 2
Dreamer - Radio 2
Turn around - Radio 2

Using this example, Radio 1 and Radio 2 play the same songs occassionally, but this may obviously cause confusion when given to the classifier. As a strategy to avoid this situation, I've come up with the following:

1) Split the training set into halves.
2) Train the classifier on the first half.
3) Test the classifier using the second half.
4) For those songs that the classifier makes a mistake on during testing, re-label the class as 'ambiguous'.
5) Train a second more robust classifier using the testing data with re-labelled examples where necessary.

Are there any fundamental issues with that sort of bootstrapping approach? Alternately, are there other techniques (clustering maybe) that can be used to identify and remove (or re-label as 'ambiguous') those training examples that are similar and thus likely to cause classification errors? I'm using Random Forest classifiers but general solutions are welcome.

Comment: Do you want to predict the radio station based on single songs? If so, your output for ambiguous songs will most likely directly correlate to the amount/ratio they are played by stations. Would instead using a batch of samples (e.g. 10 consecutive songs) work for you too?

Comment: Ideally, we want to predict radio stations based on single songs. Our aim is to have close to zero false positives, and if that means we are more conservative in our judgement (by saying 'ambiguous') in a fair amount of cases we are still fine with that. I am open to your thoughts on using groups of songs, but my overarching question is whether there is a general strategy to handle cases of ambiguous examples.

Comment: What's wrong with ambiguity? The fact is that it could have been from either radio station.

Answer (score 1):

Though what you do is technically possible, I would not strip out ambiguous songs like that. The problem is that by doing so, you lose information that would tell you something, even if being ambiguous for *some* stations. An example would be: one song is played equally by station A-Y, but not station Z. So, hearing this song would decrease the probability of station Z being the currently heard station, and would slightly increase it for all other stations.

Instead, you might want to incorporate all of this information in your model. You could e.g. try Bayesian approaches: they would enable you to a) get a proper probability per individual song for each station, and b) would allow you to increase/decrease those probabilities for each station over time, as more songs are played by the same station (which, as in the example above, would influence probability, even is they might be ambiguous for some stations).